# Where in Laravel does /public bypass router?

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-5

Laravel treats the /public directory uniquely in that the content is statically served. I have an application which requires this treatment for another folder. How can I emulate the routing-bypass behaviour for an arbitrary folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file or folder exists and is accessible in 'public' that matches the URI, the webserver will serve that file directly, since 'public' is setup as the document root/web root. If there isn't a match it will pass the request off to 'index.php' which is the front loader for the framework.

Example: For Apache there is a .htaccess file that is in the 'public' folder that directs the webserver to do this and url rewriting.